# ManagedScheduledExecutorService.schedule() in Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, schedule, quartz

I am using ManagedScheduledExecutorService.schedule() function to schedule a function call in X seconds. Is there any way I can achieve this in Quarkus?

Comment: You can schedule periodic tasks on Quarkus https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler . Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I dont want it to be periodic. I am using javax.swing.Timer now and is working fine.